# Cascading Parameter SSRS Report hangs on Production Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, cascading

I have a report in which i used two multivalue parameters Affiliate, TFN. Both fetch their available values using query. Affiliate is independent while TFN list is populated once Affiliate is selected. The report works fine when i run in development mode in ssrs. But when i deploy, it always gets stuck after i select the first parameter, Affiliate. All buttons are grayed out and i'll have to re-run the report. Report always gets stuck, regardless of the TFN result set size.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: All buttons are grayed out...does this mean all options in the affiliate control are grayed out or the TFN control is grayed out?

Comment: Yes, all options are disabled. I have to re-run the whole report.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ScriptMode="Release"`  to the scriptmanager object on your aspx webpage

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```